# How do I try Ubuntu from a USB stick?

Tags: usb

I wanted to replace windows 7 with Ubuntu.

1. Is it possible to try Ubuntu from USB, like a fully functional Ubuntu?, want to test sound, WiFI connectivity etc.
2. Is there an option to exit from the above option, in case I dont want to install Ubuntu, try it later after fixing something?

Comment: @user68186 I was in the middle of posting an answer! XD

Comment: Relevant: [What's the difference between installing and trying Ubuntu?](/q/157085/175814)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely!

You can use a software called Pen Drive Linux. The software can be found at: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows .

Once you setup your usb drive to be bootable with Ubuntu, you can then reboot your system (catch the boot menu, and boot from usb). It will let you run a liveCD version of ubuntu which is fully usable. You can use the OS to your hearts content. You can then install from the liveCD or just shutdown, remove usb drive, and start your computer like normal.

FYI people use liveCD's to do banking in a clean environment all the time. So when you make your usb drive, even if you don't use it keep it. You can always use it as a clean enviornment for shopping or online banking.

Comment: Re "people use liveCD's to do banking in a clean environment all the time"; You serious? Are you talking about the bank user or the bank **staff**?

Comment: @Pacerier bank user.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

1. You can try fully functional Ubuntu from USB without installing.
   Boot from the USB and select "Try Ubuntu" it is as simple as that. You don't have to install it to try it. Test sound, microphone, webcam, wifi and any other hardware you have works.
2. When you are done, select restart or shut down and reboot from hard drive to go back to what you have there.

See http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

and http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Good questions. The answers are easy.

> Is it possible to try ubuntu from usb, like a fully functional ubuntu?

Yes.

> Is there an option to exit from the above option?

Yes.

Enjoy Ubuntu.