# Windows user questioning his switch to Ubuntu

Tags: windows

As a long time Windows user, is it worth it to install Ubuntu over Windows? Will I still be able to use all of software and other features I currently use in Windows?

I am running a Laptop with a Core i7, 64x w/ 4gb RAM.

Which version would be best for me to install?

Comment: 64 BIT PLEASE DO NOT POST IN ALL CAPS

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I try Ubuntu from a USB stick?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/261985/how-do-i-try-ubuntu-from-a-usb-stick)

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without knowing what software you want to run.  Ubuntu will not run Windows programs natively though some can be made to run with wine.  Also there are Linux alternatives for a lot of Windows software but if you want to run a particular application you may be forced to stick with Windows.  But you can try Ubuntu without installing from a USB stick or DVD then only commit to installing if you decide you like it.

Comment: @JorgeCastro I think that this question is far off the question you linked. This is not even a duplicated. Just check the kind of answers it gathered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to install Ubuntu "over" Windows. You can install it along with it. Everything will work as is does now AND you will be able to choose to boot into Ubuntu (or your old Windows) immediately after booting up your computer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways to run Ubuntu.

If you just want to try it, I suggest downloading the live-iso, installing it to a USB Drive, and running it live from there.

To install it, you can do it wither from within Windows, or while booted from the live media.

Installing it from within Windows seems like what you want to do. This does not repartition your disk, or modify your windows files in any way, it simply modifies your boot record, and adds its files to C:.

Installing it from the live media can be tricky, because if done wring will mess up your windows install. Installing from a booted version, will involve re-partitioning your hard drive, which could result in a loss of data.

Ubuntu, like Windows and OSX, is an operating system, and requires software compiled for it specifically to run. A vast majority of what you do on your windows machine will also be supported by Ubuntu, however not all will.

Wine is an install-able windows emulator package that allows yo to run windows specific applications.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best OS is ubuntu its a lot less cluttered and you can change it to your liking. Also it has some great programs that windows might not have. However ubuntu can be problematic at times (thats why we have ask ubuntu ) I would recommend Unity as your first OS

Answer (score -1):

As I myself am a relatively new ubuntu user (I started to use it in 2011), I might not be the first person to list the benefits of this OS, but ill give you the main reason why I chose, and have stayed with this OS for a couple of years now. **Ubuntu is just a lot cleaner than Windows**.

- The screen space is not filled with pointless text and icons.
- It seems that everything that is not always necessary is hidden until you need it.