# Can you boot Ubuntu straight from a USB without installation?

Tags: usb

I want to try Ubuntu but would like to do that without making my computer dual-boot, which leads to the above question. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I try Ubuntu from a USB stick?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/261985/how-do-i-try-ubuntu-from-a-usb-stick)

Answer (score 1):

Yes that works perfectly with the Ubuntu install image. Simply [download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) the version you need and then create a bootable USB thumbdrive. If you're on windows, you can follow [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) which uses the [Pen Drive Linux's USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button) to write the image to the drive.

Once you've done that you need to boot from your usb drive (usually hitting F8 or F9 at the BIOS stage) or you change the boot order in the BIOS itself. You'll then be presented with a menu where you can **Install Ubuntu** or **Try Ubuntu without Installation**. The latter does exactly what you want: It boots Ubuntu without touching your internal drives. The system will entirely be held in the computer's memory, might however feel slow due to the nature of USB drives.

Answer (score 0):

To try Ubuntu without installation you have many choices, the easiest is

- Try the Ubuntu Live CD
- Make a USB bootable
- Try Ubuntu In a Virtual Machine

The Ubuntu Live CD is just a normal Ubuntu ISO burned to a CD/DVD, once you start booting from CD you'll be prompt with some menu. One Option of this menu is `try Ubuntu without installing` so you can choose it and this will boot the Ubuntu Live CD so you can  try Ubuntu as you like, but you should notice that every thing you do it will just wiped when you reboot unless you save your work to a storage media.

[image]

Another Option which you may be asking about is to make a bootable USB. I suppose now you are working in Windows so you can create the bootable USB. Read [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) that can explain in details what to do. 
Steps to create a live USB in Windows:

1. Download [Ubuntu ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
2. Download [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)
3. [Creating the live USB](http://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/)